# What can I do with the ender dragon's egg in Minecraft Xbox edition?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

I got the ender dragon's egg but what can I do with it?

Comment: @MrLemon both versions have the same block logic in Xbox and PC.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can place it as a decorative item.
2. You can use it as a light source, it gives out 1 light.

Be careful that it gets affected by gravity, just like gravel or sand.

Comment: How do i do nr 2

Comment: @Black.manga just place it. 1 light is way too low tho. Sun is 12, torch is 11.

Answer (score 0):

It's currently only made for cosmetic purposes, although that could change in the future.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing special with the Dragon Egg except for the fact it's a light source, which is pretty useful. You can use it as a decoration and let other players know you killed the Ender Dragon. I displayed mine in a vault I built in my house with my diamonds and gold.